# Cannot find objects from XML in Java file

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Kotlin and have been making a few very simple programs. I started to make a new program today but the textview and buttons that i have been trying to reference or use in my program aren't coming up anymore. When I write the textview id and press cntr+space I don't get any options like in previous programs. Can anyone tell me what i am suddenly doing wrong?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Class:

```
package com.hares.calculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    tvDisplay
}
```

Comment: Do you use the 'kotlin-android-extensions' plugin? And is it declared correctly in your Android-Module? If not, you either need to declare it or use the R-Class to access ur UI elements by ID.

Comment: I have checked and no the 'kotlin-android-extensions' plugin was not active. I have done that now and it has solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your activity imports should have below line

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

It is not there, you need to clean your project or you can manually add this line.